# Filedialog CustomPlaces confusion

Tags: c#, winforms, intellisense, filedialog, customplaces

I faced a strange behavior using the following code:

```
FileDialog openFileDialog1;
// ...
openFileDialog1.CustomPlaces.Add(@"C:\whatever\");
```

This compiles with no errors using .NET framework 2.0.
The code runs well under Windows 7.
But under Windows XP I get the following error at runtime:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogCustomPlacesCollection System.Windows.Forms.FilaDialog.get_CustomPlaces()'.

Trying to figure out the problem tells me:

1. Visual Studio 2005 help don't know about the `CustomPlaces` property of `FileDialog`
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.customplaces.aspx) says that this property exists only since  framework 3.5 - and *"On Windows XP, this property does not have any effect."*
3. Visual Studio 2005 intellisense offers me the exsistence of the property (so I thought using this property is fine)

That obviously doesn't fit toghether.

I still want to use the code, so I'm trying to figure out how a do check before calling it:

```
if (...) {
    openFileDialog1.CustomPlaces.Add(@"C:\whatever\");
}
```

My question is:
**Is `CustomPlaces` not supported by .NET 2.0 or is is not supported by Windows XP?**
**How do I handle this correctly?**

1) Do I have to check for the *Windows* version:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) ...
```

2) Or do I have to check for the *framework* version:

```
if (Environment.Version.Major >= 4) ...
```

3) Or both, or else !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have answered your own question in your post. The MSDN documentation clearly states that the `FileDialog.CustomPlaces` property exists only from .Net Framework 3.5 onwards. If your application is running on .Net Framework 2.0, then no, it's not supported. (Actually, looking at the [.NET 4.5 MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.customplaces(v=vs.110).aspx) for the property, it seems it's supported as of .Net Framework 2.0 SP1.)

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or higher, I would ensure that you retarget your project to compile with the .Net Framework 2.0 (RTM) if that's what framework your application will be running against. I noticed that you specifically mentioned VS 2005. If you are using VS 2005, I don't believe that has any re-targeting capabilities (if memory serves me correctly); VS2005 by default compiles against .NET Framework 2.0. Here's where things get interesting: an installation of .NET Framework 3.5 has .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 and .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 as installation pre-requisites. So, if your machine has only .NET Framework 2.0 and you want to install .NET Framework 3.5, then your .NET Framework 2.0 will be upgraded to .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 (and additionally, .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 will also be installed).

So what does this mean for you? Well, if you compile your program on a machine on which .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or higher is installed, your program will compile just fine. Furthermore, if you run the program on a machine running .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or higher, it will also run just fine. However, if you take this same program and run it on a machine which contains only the vanilla .NET Framework 2.0, you will get the error you see above because that method/property is not supported in the libraries included with the .NET Framework 2.0.

The other side of the story is the part of the MSDN documentation that says that while `FileDialog.CustomPlaces` exists from .Net Framework 2.0 SP1 and onwards, and that while that version of the Framework may be installed on Windows XP, that on Windows XP calling the property has no effect (i.e. it's a null-op, not supported by the OS). So no error should occur, but you will also see that whatever you tried to add to the `CustomPlaces` collection would not show up when you run the application on Windows XP. Again, looking at the updated documentation as of .Net Framework 4.5.x (see the link above), it clearly states that the lowest supported client operating system platform supported is Windows Vista SP2. So in all likelihood, you're out of luck when it comes to Windows XP.

If you want to do an OS version check, I would advise you to do the following check:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 &&
    Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 0 &&
    Environment.OSVersion.ServicePack == "Service Pack 2")
{
    // Add CustomPlace here...
}
```

Note that the check above will *not* allow you to add the `FileDialog.CustomPlaces` for Windows Server 2008 (even though it is supported—because through .NET, you're not able to check the `ProductTypeID` property). Furthermore, `FileDialog.CustomPlaces` is not supported on the Server Core mode of Windows until Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (but the code above *will* allow you to attempt to add the custom place, but like Windows XP, it will fail silently). In order to make a determination for these versions of Windows, you'll need to use a bit of PInvoke to access the Win32 API's `GetVersionEx` method and `OSVERSIONINFOEX` structure located in `kernel32.dll` as shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11101/OS-Name-Version-Product-Type) and/or [here](http://www.csharp411.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/OSInfo.cs).

However, generally speaking, it's not a good idea to do operating system version checks. They are notoriously difficult (especially with older operating systems). What you really need to do is to perform a .NET Framework version check. Your application apparently requires, at a minimum, .NET Framework 2.0 SP1. If you have an installer for your program, I would build in this check to your installer and optionally provide the ability to install the .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 as part of the installation of your program.

If you're not using an installer to distribute your program, then you should perform a .NET Framework version check in your application prior to attempting to add the `FileSystemCustomPlace` to the `CustomPlaces` collection to prevent the error from occurring; however, doing so will require your users with versions of Windows Vista and later to run the application with elevated permissions. Aaron Stebner has a great [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/06/16/9763379.aspx) on how to determine the .NET Framework installations that are available on your machine with example code. There is also a C# implementation of this code provided by a CodeProject.com user [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17501/Using-managed-code-to-detect-what-NET-Framework-ve).